# What's the difference between RadRails and Aptana Studio?

Tags: aptana-studio

Is one a subset of the other? Do they have the same features? I may be running low on google-fu, but I can't find a feature comparison chart or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia > Google when looking for [straightforward info](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Aptana_Studio#RadRails) ;-).

> Aptana Studio supports Ruby on Rails development using RadRails, an open source plugin for the Ruby on Rails framework.

In essence, RadRails is an Eclipse plugin, and Aptana Studio is a commercial Eclipse-derivative. That includes Radrails in the package.

Comment: So I guess that means Aptana > RadRails. Ok, thanks.